# Pass initial value to redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I want to pass initial values (coming from the props of a react-redux component) to my redux-form. But, I get not value when I inspect the data passed to the `renderField` . I followed the posts here in SO and on redux-form git forum, and I'm using `initialValues` in `mapStateToProps` but still it doesn't work.

This is my react-redux component which holds the redux-form:

```
class ShowGroup extends Component {

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>Loading group ....</div>;
    }
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <div>{this.state.error}</div>;
    }
    let group = this.props.groups[this.groupId];
    return (
      <div className="show-group">
        <form>
          <Field
            name="name"
            fieldType="input"
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label="Name"
            validate={validateName}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    groups: state.groups,
    initialValues: {
      name: 'hello'
    }
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
             //.....
    };
};

export default reduxForm({
  form:'ShowGroup'
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowGroup)
);
```

This is my renderField code:

```
export const renderField = function({ input, fieldType, label, type, meta: { touched, error }}) {
  let FieldType = fieldType;
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <div>
        <FieldType {...input} type={type} />
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are exporting the wrapped component with incorrect order

```
export default reduxForm({
  form:'ShowGroup'
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowGroup)
);
```

should be

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  form:'ShowGroup'
})(ShowGroup);
```

The reason being that the redux form HOC needs the `initialValues` prop for itself, if you reverse the order, `reduxForm` doesn't get the props rather they are passed directly to the component, which doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Is there a way to pass initial value inside the render function ? I pass 'value' property to `Field` but I get undefined anything on the `renderField` side.

Comment: You are a life saver. I spent at least 3 hours trying to figure this out.